# Tweepy solo me devuelve Tweets con fecha desde de hace un mes, no puedo obtener los anteriores!

Tags: python, twitter-api

Estoy intentando extraer datos consultando, y no importa lo que busque, solo tengo resultados de hace un mes como maximo! ayuda por favor!

```
import os
import tweepy as tw
import pandas as pd

consumer_key= '-------------'
consumer_secret= '----------'
access_token= '---------------'
access_token_secret= '---------------'

auth = tw.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tw.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)

search_words = "ggal"
date_since = "2020-05-01"
date_until = "2020-05-30"
tweets = tw.Cursor(api.search,
              q=search_words,
              lang="es",
              until=date_until,
              since=date_since).items(5)
data = [[tweet.created_at, tweet.text] for tweet in tweets]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=[ 'date', 'tweet_text'])
df2
```

Creo que el codigo va bien, no se que podría ser que falte o si existe algún otro método, quisiera hacer un análisis de sentimientos pero estoy trabado en la extracción, agradecería mucho la ayuda de la comunidad, gracias!

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! tendra que ver con las fechas? estas buscando cosas de mayo solamente...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como respondieron [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34424142/6217040), Tweepy usa el API de Twitter, el cual limita los resultados a un rango de 1 mes como máximo.

Tienes otras opciones como [Twint](https://github.com/twintproject/twint), que aunque es más lento, te permite obtener resultados más antiguos.

Comment: Muchisimas Gracias por la respuesta! ya voy a probar con otro método!